# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method "playFlash" of undefined

Tags: navegador-de-internet, raspberry-pi

Este programa server para aparecer um website e fazer autoplay de umas músicas, o código tem funcionado sem problemas em windows e android, e os browsers testados form o IE, Firefox, Chrome e Opera. Contudo, estive a tentar corrê-lo através de um raspberry pi com o SO Pipplware e com os browsers Chromium e Iceweasel. Até agora nunca consegui pô-lo a funcionar.  Aparecem os seguintes erros:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method "playFlash" of undefined"
>
> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(not found)"

Será incompatibilidade com os browsers? Eu estou a tentar modificar o código de maneira a pô-lo funcional mas não tenho muita experiência. Agradeço se alguém poder ajudar. Obrigado.
O código que dá o erro encontra-se abaixo, na linha 127.
Se for necessário mais alguma edição, eu disponibilizarei.

```
$.fn.simulateClick = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if('createEvent' in document) {
            var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView,
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt); // line 127 
        } else {
            this.click(); // IE
        }
    });
}
```

Para a ajudar a perceber qual é o problema, vou postar o index completo(já com as alterações).

```
function centrar(caixa){    
    //Centra uma caixa
    $(caixa).css("position","relative");
    $(caixa).css("top", ($(window).height() - $(caixa).height()) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    if($(caixa).position().top < 0){
        $(caixa).css("top",5);
    }
}

window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    $("#caixa_central").show();
    centrar("#caixa_central");
    //posicionar_caixa("#caixa_central");
}

//Posiciona a caixa ao fazer rezise
$(window).resize(function() {
    centrar("#caixa_central");
    //posicionar_caixa("#caixa_central");
});


 function radio_janela(id_ambiente){

    var dataString = 'id_ambiente=' + id_ambiente;  
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "radio.php",
      data: dataString,  
      success: function(data){
        $("#pesquisa_resultado").html(data);
      }  
    });

 } 

 /*------------------- Fun��o para pesquisar ------------- */
 function pesquisar(){
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "pesquisar.php",
      success: function(data){
        $("#pesquisa_resultado").html("");
        $("#pesquisa_resultado").html(data);
        centrar("#caixa_central");
        //posicionar_caixa("#caixa_central");
      }  
    });
 }

 <?php
    if(empty($_GET["ambiente"])){
        echo "pesquisar();";
    } else {
        echo "radio_janela(".$_GET["ambiente"].");";
    }
 ?>


var simulateClick = function(controle) {
    if (controle) {
        if (control.click !== undefined) 
        controle.click();
        else {
            if('createEvent' in document) {
            var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView,1,0,0,0,0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
} else {
     this.click(); // IE
}
    }
}
else alert("Controle não localizado!");
}   

window.setInterval(function(){
    $('.edithost').simulateClick();                         
}, 1000);
```

simulate.Click atualização

$(document).ready(function(){

simulateClick(document.getElementById("id_ambiente"));
simulateClick($(".button btn green")[0])
$(".button btn green").each(function(){simulateClick(this)})
    var simulateClick = function(controle) {
        if (controle) {
            if (control.click !== undefined) 
            controle.click();
            else {
                if('createEvent' in document) {
                var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                    evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView,1,0,0,0,0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else {
         this.click(); // IE
    }
        }
    }
    else alert("Controle não localizado!");
}

```
window.setInterval(function(){
simulateClick($(".edithost")[0]);                           
}, 1000);

    });
```

Comment: Pelo erro `404` deu alguma coisa errado, não conseguiu recuperar alguma coisa do servidor.

Comment: @Maicon Carraro   Pois, o mysql vinha com uns erros inicialmente, juntamente com phpmyadmin, também poderá ser disso? Alguns consegui resolver, outros nem por isso. Mas o mysql connecta e funciona, só não sei é se está a 100% ou se está mesmo a impedir que o javascript funcione. Os últimos erros que estive a resolver nem conse gui, porque eram termos que em que a única solução estava "depricated" e ainda não há substitutuinte, que é caso do "can´t ceate test file..." e "Can´t change dir ...".

Answer (score 0):

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method "playFlash" of undefined"

Significa que você tentou chamar um método em um controle que não existe ou não pode ser localizado. Deve haver alguma incompatibilidade no método ou no jquery que localiza o controle ao qual você chamará o método simulateClick. Tente sempre testar antes de fazer qualquer coisa em um controle se o mesmo exite (ou foi devidamente localizado). Tente ver também se você não chamou um método para o controle antes de tê-lo instanciado (criado).

Teste sempre antes se já existe o evento click antes de criar um evento em dispatch, pois assim fica mais fácil tanto para nós como para o browser interpretar. Todos os navegadores modernos suportam os eventos click, talvez nem seja necessário criar o evento do dispatch.

Para mantê-lo compatível sem a necessidade de jquery, recomendo que utilize javascript puro para isso. Assim você poderia utilizar algo assim:

```
var simulateClick = function(controle){
    if (controle){
       if (controle.click !== undefined)
        controle.click();
       else {
             if('createEvent' in document) {
        var doc = this.ownerDocument,
            evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView,
                  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else {
        this.click();
    }
       }
    }
    else alert("Controle não Localizado!");
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Editado. Chame o método de uma das seguintes maneiras:

```
simulateClick(document.getElementById("id_do_controle"));
simulateClick($(".classe_css_do_controle")[0]) //Pega o primeiro controle com a classe
$(".classe_css_do_controle").each(function(){simulateClick(this)}) //Executa a função em todos os controles contendo a classe definida
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, foi muito completa e bem explicada. Eu alterei código tal como sugeriu, no entanto agora aparecem ainda mais erros, "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'simulateClick'. Reparei que existe mais uma porção de código que corresponde à função, Mas não acho que influencie, os erros continuam a vir do dispatchEvent(evt);. `window.setInterval(function(){$('.edithost').simulateClick();}, 1000);`

Comment: Também procurei e não reparei em métodos que não fossem previamente criados, mas como disse, não tenho muita experiência. Vou editar a pergunta e por o ficheiro do index completo.

Comment: Troque o 
       $('.edithost').simulateClick();                         
Para
simulateClick($(".edithost")[0]) se for só um controle
Ou
$(".edithost").each(function(){simulateClick(this)}) se for mais de um
Como trocamos uma função jqery para uma comum não há como chamá-la como método de um objeto

Comment: Se puder poste o html deste(s) controles nos quais vc quer simular o click. Para que vc precisa deste timeout para fazer o click? Se você estiver tentando executar algo após o carregamento da página, tente usar o $(document).ready(function(){//Código a executar}) no seu lugar

Comment: Peço desculpa pela a demora a responder mas o meu tutor de estágio achou melhor mudar de SO no raspberry. Assim que testar tudo e  caso volte ao mesmo, eu sigo as instruções que forneceu. Muito obrigado mesmo pelo apoio, foi bastante útil.

Comment: Ok, já tenho o Raspbian instalado, no entanto excepto algumas incompatibilidades, os erros surgiram exactamente iguais. Já modifiquei o código que me disse para alterar e agora apenas aparece um erro  >Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   na linha   `simulate.Click(document.getElementById("id_ambient"));` Substitui com a class do controle como disse, e também experimentei o tal código que me sugeriu para correr após o carregamento da página.

Comment: Tente usar somente
    simulateClick(document.getElementById("id_ambient"));
Pois
    simulate.Click(document.getElementById("id_ambient"));
Vai procurar uma função com o nome de Click em um objeto simulate que não existe. Este ponto após o simulate deve estar gerando a exceção